# Kotlin enforce data class type

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I have various types of `events` in my application that are represented by Data classes.

All `events` must have an attribute called `EventContent` that stores additional data about the event in String format. These events are saved to a database and `EventContent` is serialized into a JSON via kotlin.x.serialization.

To enforce this, I have used an interface like this on a sample event called `ShutdownEvent`:

```
interface Event {
    var eventContent: String
}


data class ShutdownEvent(
    override var eventContent: String
) : Event
```

Now imagine for the specific event called `ShutdownEvent`, I know its `EventContent` must have only 2 attributes: `trigger` and `location`, both of which are Strings. How can I enforce that the `EventContent` follows this structure.

I was hoping for something like this:

```
data class ShutdownEvent(
    @Serializable(with = ShutdownContentConverter::class) override var eventContent: ShutdownData,
) : Event


@Serializable
data class ShutdownData(
   var trigger: String,
   var location: String,
)
```

But this causes problems with my `Event` interface implementation, because it expects the `eventContent` attribute to be a String. Is there an easy way to make this work?

---

**Edit:**

I would appreciate an answer that allows me to process my events as follows:

```
fun process(event: Event) {
    if (event is ShutdownEvent) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to deal with this is to make your interface generic in the "event content" type, instead of using String:

```kotlin
interface Event<C> {
    var eventContent: C
}

data class ShutdownEvent(
    @Serializable(with = ShutdownContentConverter::class)
    override var eventContent: ShutdownData,
) : Event<ShutdownData>

@Serializable
data class ShutdownData(
   var trigger: String,
   var location: String,
)
```

If all possible types of event content have some common properties, you can define a parent `EventContent` interface like this:

```kotlin
/** A parent interface for all types of event content. */
interface EventContent {
    val someCommonProp: String
}

interface Event<C : EventContent> {
    var eventContent: C
}

data class ShutdownEvent(
    @Serializable(with = ShutdownContentConverter::class)
    override var eventContent: ShutdownData,
) : Event<ShutdownData>

@Serializable
data class ShutdownData(
    override val someCommonProp: String,
    var trigger: String,
    var location: String,
) : EventContent
```

Side note: I would strongly advise to use `val` instead of `var` everywhere here. You probably don't want event data to be mutable. Once the event is created no-one should really modify it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Perhaps a follow up question: how can I check what type of Event I got if a func expects an `Event` type? With a generic, I cannot simply do `if (event is ShutdownEvent)`

Comment: I added an edit at the bottom of the question. Thank you!

Comment: *With a generic, I cannot simply do if (event is ShutdownEvent)* - @john why not? This should work fine, because `ShutdownEvent` is not generic itself

Comment: for example imagine I have a fun that saves the event to the DB. The fun signature looks like save(event: Event<*>) and I am trying to save the eventContent attribute with Exposed like this it[eventContent] = Json.encodeToString(event.eventContent). But kotlinx.serialization throws `Serializer for class 'Any' is not found. Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly.`

Comment: I guess the solution is to manually check and cast each object before saving. For example this works fine: `Json.encodeToString((event as ShutdownEvent).eventContent)` Do let me know if there is a way to infer the type automatically :)

Comment: If you actually use the `if (event is ShutdownEvent)` that you mentioned, this type will automatically be inferred within the `if` block without the need for a cast (`as`).